# Is there any way to target href in anchor tag through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to target href in anchor tag through javascript? If not then what should I use?

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="*I want to inject here through javascript or Jquery">
```

Comment: why do you want to target it? I mean what are you doing to do after targeting?

Comment: `$("a").attr("href", "change it to this")` or `$("a").prop("href", "change it to this")` I haven't checked for href.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same as Divyesh but pure javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('link'); 
a.href = "www.newlink.com";
```

or chained if you don't need a reference to a

```
document.getElementById('link').href = "www.newlink.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using jquery as follow

```
<a id="link" href="*I want to inject here through javascript or Jquery">
```

And in jquery

```
$("#link").attr("href","www.newlink.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript:

```
    document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "http://www.yourUrl.com");
```